# Open ios Storyboard view from CDVPlugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins

I work about an integration API in a CordovaPlugin in an ios app.

I can execute some objectiveC code with a custom plugin, but now the api need a presentViewController to work.

I think i need a storyBoard with his UIViewController to get it work.

Can someone tell me if it's possible ? i tried some tutorials but nothing is going right..

Thanks for help
( excuse my poor english ! )